# how to casting a string to integer in html flask view

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Hello everyone i want someone to help me  to convert a variable  to integer inside a loop for  , this is the item  :

```
<li>the score is : {{item.score|int * 100}} %</li>
```

i got this :

```
<li>0.03618881106376648</li>
```

and my goal is to get the result like this

```
<li>3%</li>
```

please if anyone have a solution ! thanx

Comment: as for me you should conver it in code before you send it to template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li>the score is : {{ '{0:0.0f}'.format(item.score * 100) }}%</li>
```

Comment: probalby should also works `'{0:.0%}'.format(item.score)` but I didn't check it in template